# HTML overlay height to cover entire visible page

Tags: html, css, dom, jquery-ui

I have a web page that loads some stuff using AJAX. I want to display an overlay with a loading indicator while the loading is in progress, so that the user cannot interact with most of the page - except the menu at the top. I'm using jQuery and the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) to do this.

I call $(element).block() and it works fine, but the overlay only extends as far down as the current content of my page. As more content is loaded and added to the page the overlay moves down with it and this looks a bit ugly. Ideally I'd like it to cover the entire visible area of the page right from the start. A simple hack for doing this would be to set a large height value for the overlay, like this:

```
$(myElement).block({
        overlayCSS: {
            height: '10000px'
        }
 });
```

... but this creates a scrollbar! How do I avoid this and make it just the right height to cover the visible page, but not enlarge it?

Answer (score 24):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute`. This way the overlay will not move even if you scroll.

Comment: Dude thanks for this answer. This problem was driving me crazy!

Comment: position fixed is the solution, and if the page is using headers and footers dynamically loaded/added through another template, make sure to place the overlay div at right place so that it covers header and footer as well...

Answer (score 2):

In XHTML the html and body elements are not quite as magical as in HTML. The body element doesn't fill the viewport (window) automatically, it's size is only as tall as it's contents.

To make an element fill the window you first have to make the html and body elements fill the window:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Then you can use `height: 100%;` on an element in the body to make it cover the full height.

Comment: The explanation makes sense and it sounded promising, but doesn't quite work on my page. I think it's because it also uses jQuery UI tabs, dynamically loaded and I suspect that every element from <html> down must have "height: 100%" set.

Answer (score 1):

The following code ended up working for me:

```
$("body").block({
  message: '<h2>Loading...</h2>',
  overlayCSS: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '0',
    bottom: '0',
    left: '0',
    right: '0'
  }
});

body {
  color: #004A6E;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I used the following post as a reference: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)
the one modification that I had to do was adding left and right. My overlay was covering only the half of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position` to `absolute` and height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a complete example for you, now you can use that in your application and and just hide it after ajax request completed.

Click [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/safkass/279ME/1/)!

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div id="container">
    content Whatever you want even you can delete this container
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me! I changed `absolute` to `fixed`.

```js
function showWaitPopup() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('bkdiv');
  if (obj) {
    obj.style.display = 'block';
  }
  return true;
}

showWaitPopup();
```

```css
div.bkdiv {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  z-index: 2000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bkdiv" id="bkdiv"></div>
```